# Dependent C++ project binaries not relinked in Netbeans

Tags: c++, netbeans, makefile

I've got a two projects in Netbeans. The first a library, and the second an application. The application depends on the library. When I make changes to the library and attempt to run the application the library is rebuilt, however the library and application object files are *NOT* relinked unless I first clean both projects, which is needless and time-consuming.

How can I force Netbeans to link a rebuilt library with the application object files in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the application project referenced the library project (by name) incorrectly. The solution was to add the library project like so:

Project Properties -> Build -> Linker -> Libraries -> Browser and select library project file (don't just type library file name).